# USACO Training Pages Your Ride Is Here ArrayList IndexOutOfBounds Error

Tags: java

Problem: 
Your Ride Is Here

It is a well-known fact that behind every good comet is a UFO. These UFOs often come to collect loyal supporters from here on Earth. Unfortunately, they only have room to pick up one group of followers on each trip. They do, however, let the groups know ahead of time which will be picked up for each comet by a clever scheme: they pick a name for the comet which, along with the name of the group, can be used to determine if it is a particular group's turn to go (who do you think names the comets?). The details of the matching scheme are given below; your job is to write a program which takes the names of a group and a comet and then determines whether the group should go with the UFO behind that comet.

Both the name of the group and the name of the comet are converted into a number in the following manner: the final number is just the product of all the letters in the name, where "A" is 1 and "Z" is 26. For instance, the group "USACO" would be 21 * 19 * 1 * 3 * 15 = 17955. If the group's number mod 47 is the same as the comet's number mod 47, then you need to tell the group to get ready! (Remember that "a mod b" is the remainder left over after dividing a by b; 34 mod 10 is 4.)

Write a program which reads in the name of the comet and the name of the group and figures out whether according to the above scheme the names are a match, printing "GO" if they match and "STAY" if not. The names of the groups and the comets will be a string of capital letters with no spaces or punctuation, up to 6 characters long.

Here is my code for the problem:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ride {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ride.out")));


    ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>(10);

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        inputs.set(i, st.nextToken());
    }

    ArrayList<String> inputs2 = new ArrayList<String>(10);

    st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        inputs2.set(j, st.nextToken());
    }

    String[] alphabet = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    ArrayList<String> alphabet2 = new ArrayList<String>(30);
    {
        for (int a = 0; a<alphabet.length; a++)
        {
            alphabet2.set(a, alphabet[a]);
        }
    }

    int product1 = 1;
    for (int k=0; k<inputs.size(); k++)
    {
        String letter = inputs.get(k);
        product1 = product1*(alphabet2.indexOf(letter)+1);

    }

    int product2 = 1;
    for (int l=0; l<inputs2.size(); l++)
    {
        String letter2 = inputs2.get(l);
        product2 = product2*(alphabet2.indexOf(letter2)+1);

    }

    if (product1%47 == product2%47)
    {
        out.print("GO");
    }


    else
    {
        out.print("STAY");
    }

    out.close();
    f.close(); 


}
```

}

However, when I run this, the grader returns:

> Run 1: Execution error: Your program exited with exit status `1'.

```
    ------ Data for Run 1 [length=14 bytes] ------
    COMETQ 
    HVNGAT 
    ----------------------------

      Your program printed data to stderr.  Here is the data:
      -------------------
      Exception_in_thread_"main"_java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:_Index:_0,_Size:_0
        at_java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
        at_java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:337)
        at_ride.main(Unknown_Source)
      -------------------
```

Can anyone help point out my problem?

Comment: Well, the debugger should show you the exact line where the array index was out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set` method on a `List` requires that [there already be an element at the index before the set is called for that index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-).

So this code is breaking since you do a `set` on an empty list:

```
ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>(10);

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    inputs.set(i, st.nextToken());
}
```

The more appropriate method to use would be [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-):

```
ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>(10);

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    inputs.add(i,st.nextToken());
}
```